# Differences between HTML element and XML element?

Tags: xml, dom

```
xmlElement.constructor

ElementConstructor

htmlElement.constructor

HTMLSelectElementConstructor
```

So I found xmlElement doesn't have methods like `getElementsByTagName()` and other a few?

How can I get the tag with a give name name in a xmlElement node?

-----update-----

actually they are the same, and there's no difference so far, I just problem is due to:

```
anyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

anyElement[0].getElementsByTagName('p'); // TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

but

```
element = anyElement[0];

element.getElementsByTagName('p')// this work
```

how does this happen if I only assign to another variable?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is a standard bit of DOM, it should be available on any XML element. It would make your question easier to answer if you told us which DOM API you were using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the large part the APIs are very similar however HTML is a lot less strict than XML so I should imagine that it has more error handling stuff.